# Regex issue: replace the first and the last $ character from all the elements of an array

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace few words from a huge string with `preg_replace()`
using it like this :

```
preg_replace($match[0], $variable_value_array, $form_body)
```

Here `$match[0]` is an array with value in it in the form like:

```
$contacts-firstname$
$contacts-lastname$
$contacts-mobile$
$leads-leadstatus$
$leads-noofemployees$
```

and `$variable_value_array` is also an array with values in it like :

```
Linda
William
(091) 115-9385
Value Not Present
Value Not Present
```

and `$form_body` is a really long `string`.

The function is replacing the values of `$form_body` but instead of replacing the whole `$contacts-firstname$` with **`Linda`** it is replacing only **`contacts-firstname`** with **`Linda`** making it like `$Linda$`. What should i do to replace both the **$** sigh's as well ?
Thanks.

Comment: You will need to escape the [end anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for matching a literal "`$`"

Comment: @Bergi it's not an anchor here but the pattern's delimiter

Comment: @m.buettner: Ah, right. I was not sure of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `$` is interpreted as the delimiter of your regex. You should use a simple [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) instead. The signature is exactly the same:

```
str_replace($match[0], $variable_value_array, $form_body);
```

If you desperately wanted to use `preg_replace` you need to do two things. Firstly, you need to wrap every array element in explicit delimiters (`/` is kind of the standard choice). And also you need to run every array element through [`preg_quote`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), otherwise the `$` will be treated as an end-of-string anchors:

```
$patterns = array();
foreach($match[0] as $value)
    $patterns[] = '/'.preg_quote($value, '/').'/';
```

And then use `$patterns` instead of `$match[0]`. But that is only intended as a nice-to-know if you ever actually need to use an array of literal search-strings inside a more complex pattern.

Comment: I did this your way. but just out of curiosity, how to do this with `preg_replace` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace` its faster and much appropriate for your use case